# DatePicker dialog with preselected value from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-datepicker

I have a datepicker dialog that opens on clicking on edittext. What i want is that when i click on edittext the datepicker dialog should show date that was already present in edittext.

My code: 
**Xml code:**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="Date Of Birth"
            android:textSize="12sp"
         android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
            android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
```

**Java code:**

```
dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        String myFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"; // your format
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());

                        dob.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                    }

                };
                new DatePickerDialog(PersonalDetailsFormActivity.this, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            }
        });
```

I have been through many links online but all show how to set date in edittext but what i want opposite to this. There is a value in edittext and the datepicker dialog should open with that date as pre-selected value.

Comment: what kind of problem you faced now?

Comment: @sasikumar : See i have an edittext with a date value filled in it. When i click on that edittext i want to show the value already stored in edittext into datepicker.

Comment: @jeevikadhillon please check my Updated Answer.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Enter Date in MM/DD/YYYY Format and Click on Edittext so DatePicker popup with entered date.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package mydemo.com.datepiker;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String date = "";
    EditText edittext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Make sure user insert date into edittext in this format.
                Date dateObject;
                try {
                    String dob_var = (edittext.getText().toString());
                    dateObject = formatter.parse(dob_var);
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObject);

                    String[] items1 = date.split("/");
                    String d1 = items1[0];
                    String m1 = items1[1];
                    String y1 = items1[2];
                    int d = Integer.parseInt(d1);
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(m1);
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(y1);

                    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            String date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                                    + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
                            edittext.setText(date);
                        }
                    }, y, m - 1, d);
                    datePicker.show();

                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("Exception is: ", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mydemo.com.datepiker.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Enter Date:"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Hope this may help you now.

Comment: Dear this code is to set the date in edittext. But what i want is different. There is some value in edittext already and when i click on that edittext i want the datepicker dialog to open with the date that is already present in the edittext.

Comment: Hey Enter date in dd/MM/yyyy in edittext and then see above snippet then set this date in DatePicker. that date set final in Toast see.

Comment: @jeevikadhillon please check my Updated Answer. hope this may help you now.

Comment: Thanks  @InsaneCat

Comment: @jeevikadhillon Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can call datePickerDialog with params,

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
```

Here month, date and year are integers.

Find below Sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText chooseDate;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private Date date;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chooseDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.choose_date);

    chooseDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    chooseDate.setText(formatter.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                }

            };
            try {
                if (chooseDate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    date = new Date();

                } else {
                    date = formatter.parse(chooseDate.getText().toString());
                }
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, mDateSetListener, year, month, day).show();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ParseException" + e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What is mDateSetListener?

Comment: Reference of `OnDateSetListener`

Comment: Amazing @Archana, Thanks! This was actually needed. :)

Comment: @InsaneCat I'm not sure why you're claiming credit on another answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need use the method updateDate(year, month, dayOfMonth) to set the date of the DatePicker.

**Sample code:**

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
datePicker.updateDate(2018, 9, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit text

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_Date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

inside the activity

```
txt_Date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Date);
 txt_Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layDatePicket.setEnabled(false);
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity.this,
                        listener, calender.get(Calendar.YEAR), calender.get(Calendar.MONTH), calender.get(Calendar.DATE));
              // set your date in the above line.
                dialog.show();                                    
            }
        });
```

Implement the listener here.

```
 listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + ((month < 10) ? "0" + month : month) + "/" + year;
                txt_datepicker.setText(date);
            }
        };
```